# ¿Cómo lograr que una query no recupere determinado dato?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla3

**Tengo esta query:**

```
$condicion = '`b`.`SubmissionId` = 100 OR `b`.`SubmissionId` = 111 OR `b`.`SubmissionId` = 112';
    $query
        ->select('a.SubmissionId, b.SubmissionId, b.FieldName, b.FieldValue')
        ->from($db->quoteName('#__rsform_submissions', 'a'))
        ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__rsform_submission_values', 'b') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('a.SubmissionId') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('b.SubmissionId') . ')')
        ->where($condicion);
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $resultado2 = $db->loadRowList();
```

Al ejecutar la query anterior, recupero un array parecido a este:

```
$miArray (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => 105
        [1] => 105
        [2] => nombre
        [3] => Johny
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => 105
        [1] => 105
        [2] => apellido
        [3] => Pérez
        )
    [2] => Array (
        [0] => 105
        [1] => 105
        [2] => telefono
        [3] => 5567654567
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [0] => 105
        [1] => 105
        [2] => telefono_alter
        [3] => 25567654567
    )
)
```

El **105** se repite 2 veces en cada elemento del array padre. El 105 corresponde con *a.SubmissionId* y *b.SubmissionId*.

¿Cómo lograr que el **105** se imprima sólo una vez, o ninguna?

Comment: Si entendí bien, quitándolos del select, tal vez? `->select('a.SubmissionId, b.FieldName, b.FieldValue')`

Comment: @Shaz, ¿Pero si los quito del select, cómo hago la comparación en el **join**? ¿Será que puedo seguir usando a.SubmissionId sin que esté declarado en el select? Voy a probar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo estas llamando dos veces, es por eso que sale dos veces, debieras llamarlo solo una vez, de cualquiera de la dos tablas.